# java - passing type of array of Vectors argument, to function as a Class<T> type parameter

Tags: java

I am given a function that expects parameter:

```
Class<T> type
```

but the argument that I am sending to the function is

```
Vector<TransactionData>[]
```

I tried

```
Vector<TransactionData>[].class
```

but i get a error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got what error?

Comment: Generics don't exist at runtime, so the class is just `Vector[].class`.

Comment: Also, you can't even create an array of a generic type. `new Vector<TransactionData>[123]` is illegal syntax.

Answer (score 2):

See Java type erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

At runtime only the raw types exist, so you cannot take the class of a parameterized type:

`Vector<TransactionData>.class`          -- wrong

`Vector.class`                           -- ok

`Vector<TransactionData>[].class`        -- wrong

`Vector[].class`                         -- ok

Comment: A little comment: `TransactionData` is `Object` at run-time.